# Blank Memory error when trying to divide the numpy image array by 255

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, image-recognition

Here I'm basically trying to predict age and gender by some images and labels through image recognition. But I'm getting the below error when I'm trying to divide the image numpy array by 255 to normalize it.

```
import csv
import os
from pathlib import *

dir_path = Path('C:\\Users\\Yeshan\\Desktop\\my projs\\UTKFace')
files = dir_path.glob('*.jpg')

import cv2
ages=[]
genders=[]
images=[]

for fle in files:
    filename = Path(fle).name
    age=int(str(filename).split('_')[0])
    ages.append(age)
    gender = int(str(filename).split('_')[1])
    genders.append(gender)
    
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dir_path,filename))
    
    image= cv2.resize(img,(48,48))
    images.append(image)

labels=[]
i=0
while i<len(ages):
  label=[]
  label.append([ages[i]])
  label.append([genders[i]])
  labels.append(label)
  i+=1

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

images_f=np.array(images)
print(images[0])
labels_f=np.array(labels)

images_f_2=images_f/255
```

The error:

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 images_f_2=images_f/255
> MemoryError:

BTW: I did try =/ 255 and still did not work, tried converting to float and dividing and still no luck.

And this is how images_f array looks like:

```
array([[[[196, 201, 210],
         [176, 183, 192],
         [127, 137, 146],
         ...,
         [103, 100,  99],
         [ 97,  96,  91],
         [103,  95,  91]],

        [[197, 202, 211],
         [140, 147, 156],
         [123, 134, 142],
         ...,
         [108, 109, 107],
         [103, 100,  99],
         [105,  95,  95]],

        [[188, 193, 202],
         [155, 162, 171],
         [141, 152, 160],
```

Comment: How large are your images, how many do you have, and how much RAM do you have? It could just be that you ran out of memory. Note: you can get the size in bytes of a numpy array by doing `import sys` and then `sys.getsizeof(images)`.

Comment: i got 8gb ram and the total image size folder is 114MB , @Anakhand, i used sys and it showed me this '163869840'

Comment: Assuming that your image is a numpy array once you've done a resize (from memory I think cv2 does work with numpy arrays). You could just do the /255 at that point `image = cv2.resize(img,(48,48)) / 255`

Comment: `/255` converts to floats, i.e. you need minimum 9 times the memory of your `images` size (8 times for the new float array and 1 time until gc for the original uint array). If your `images` array is 156 MB you need an additional 1.2 GB for the new array. Obviously you don't have so much memory available.

Comment: Uhm i t was just a memory error dude, i restarted my machine and then it worked, thnx guys anyways.

Answer (score -1):

Just restart your machine and try again.